# solving higher orders of boundary value problems numerically

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I want to solve a sixthorder Boundary Value Problem Numerically. 
(I have reduced the sixth order of this problem to a system of first order odes.) But I do not know that how to apply the boundary conditions on it. My  fourth-order problem is:
$$\frac{Ad^4w}{d\zeta^4}+\frac{Bd^2w}{d\zeta^2}+{Cw}+\frac{D}{(1-w)^2}+\frac{E}{(1-w)^3}=0$$
Boundary\space Conditions:
$$\zeta=0 \rightarrow
\begin{cases}
w(0)=0   \\[2ex]
\frac{dw(0)}{d\zeta}=0
\end{cases}
,~~~~
\zeta=1 \rightarrow
\begin{cases}
\frac{d^2w(0)}{d\zeta^2}=0    \\[2ex]
\frac{d^3w(0)}{d\zeta^3}=0  
\end{cases}
$$

I want to solve this ode numerically and I have reduced the order and I generated a system of first order ode's. But I want to solve this problem by shooting method and I do not know how to apply the boundary conditions on it.

---

Also, how to apply this on the sixth-order problem $$\frac{Ad^6w}{d\zeta^6}+ \frac{Bd^5w}{d\zeta^5}+\frac{Cd^4w}{d\zeta^4}+\frac{Dd^3w}{d\zeta^3}+{Ew}+\frac{F}{(1-w)^2}+\frac{G}{(1-w)^3}=0$$
Boundary\space Conditions:

$$\zeta=0 \rightarrow
\begin{cases}
w(0)=0   \\
\frac{dw(0)}{d\zeta}=0  \\
\frac{d^3w(0)}{d\zeta^3}=0
\end{cases}
,~~~\zeta=1 \rightarrow
\begin{cases}
w(1)=0 \\
\frac{dw(1)}{d\zeta}=0 \\
\frac{d^3w(1)}{d\zeta^3}=0
\end{cases}
$$

is it possible to consider $w(1)=0$  as $\frac{d^2w(0)}{\zeta^2}=a_0$, $w'(1)$ as $\frac{Cd^4w(0)}{\zeta^4}=b_0$, $w'''(0)$ as $\frac{Cd^5w(0)}{\zeta^5}=c_0$

I would be appreciating if somebody could help me that which methods are suitable for such problems.

Comment: Please ask a new question or add to the old question, do not overwrite a question that already has a valid answer. Is it $\dfrac{d^kw(ζ)}{dζ^k}$ or do you mean $\dfrac{w^{(k)}(ζ)}{ζ^k}$?

Comment: It is $\frac{d^kw(\zeta)}{d\zeta^k}$

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the [shooting method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method). So you will start with the initial conditions $w(0)=w'(0)=0$ and $w''(0)=a_0$ and $w'''(0)=b_0$. Then simulate the system and check the values $w''(1)$ and $w'''(1)$. I would create a grid of $a_0,b_0$ values and let multiple simulations run. Then look what is closest to your boundary conditions, then refine the grid points of $a_0,b_0$ and simulate the system again. Proceed until you have found a solution that is precise enough.

Just to summarize. You turn the boundary value problem into an initial value problem with two parameters. You tune the two parameters such that you get closer to the solution of the boundary value problem.

Comment: How to apply on this  $\frac{Ad^6w}{\zeta^6}+ \frac{Bd^5w}{\zeta^5}+\frac{Cd^4w}{\zeta^4}+\frac{Dd^3w}{\zeta^3}+{Cw}+\frac{E}{(1-w)^2}+\frac{F}{(1-w)^3}=0$
$Boundary\space Conditions:$

$\zeta=0 \rightarrow
\begin{cases}
w(0)=0   \\
\frac{dw(0)}{d\zeta}=0 & \\
\frac{d^3w(0)}{d\zeta^3}=0 & \text{}
\end{cases}
$

$\zeta=1 \rightarrow
\begin{cases}
w(1)=0 \\
\frac{dw(1)}{d\zeta}=0 &\\
\frac{d^3w(1)}{d\zeta^3}=0 & \text{}
\end{cases}
$\ is it possible to consider w(1)=0  as$\frac{d^2w(0)}{\zeta^2}=a0, w'(1) as \frac{d^4w(0)}{\zeta^4}=b0, w'''(0)as \frac{d^5w(0)}{\zeta^5}=c0$